# Ansible Jinja templating check if multiple values are undefined before using default(omit)

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

I have this block

```
url_username: "{{ download.username | default(omit) }}"
```

I want to say if `download.username` is not defined, see if `offline_download` is defined. If both are not defined then use default(omit). Something like

```
url_username: "{{ download.username | offline_download | default(omit) }}"
```

Obviously my syntax above is wrong while pipe'ing. So what is the right way to do?

Basically check if multiple values are defined before doing the default(omit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [*default*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.default) recursively

```yaml
url_username: "{{ username | d(offline | d(omit)) }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    url_username: "{{ username | d(offline | d(omit)) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: url_username
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e username=value_of_username pb.yml

  url_username: value_of_username
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e offline=value_of_offline pb.yml

  url_username: value_of_offline
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

  url_username: __omit_place_holder__eb8bf53eb654413fef765058f68f455d9e0a191e
```